# Spring ACL with Kotlin Exposed

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, acl, kotlin-exposed

I'm using kotlin exposed and spring acl: JdbcMutableAclService.

The dummy code looks like:

```
transaction {
   //operation 1
   dao.updateSomething(resourceId)
   val sids = dao.getUserIdsByResourceId(resourceId)

   //operation 2
   val pObjectIdentity = ObjectIdentityImpl(PROJECT, resourceId)
   val pMutableAcl = aclService.readAclById(pObjectIdentity) as MutableAcl

   var i = pMutableAcl.entries.size
   sids.forEach {
      pMutableAcl.insertAce(i++, BasePermission.READ, PrincipalSid(it), true)
   }
   aclService.updateAcl(pMutableAcl)

   //operation 3
   val rObjectIdentity = ObjectIdentityImpl(RESOURCE, resourceId)
   val rMutableAcl = aclService.readAclById(rObjectIdentity) as MutableAcl

   var i = rMutableAcl.entries.size
   sids.forEach {
      rMutableAcl.insertAce(i++, BasePermission.READ, PrincipalSid(it), true)
   }
   aclService.updateAcl(rMutableAcl)
}
```

If something happens in operation 3 - it won't write nothing to db, the outer transaction will also rolled back, and operation 1 won't be committed as well.
Unfortunately operation 2 won't be rolled back.

So my assumption every time of using `updateAcl` it creates its own isolated transaction.

I don't know how it work in case of Spring Jpa, and @Transactional annotation (is JdbcMutableAclService take into consideration outer transaction or not), but in case of Exposed it is not.

Is it correct behaviour at all? Should every acl update be an isolated transaction?

Is there a way to integrate Exposed and JdbcMutableAclService without implementing my own MutableAclService?

**UPD for @Tapac**
I'm using `org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-spring-boot-starter` without any additional configuration, so based on `ExposedAutoConfiguration` it is `org.jetbrains.exposed.spring.SpringTransactionManager`.
But during the debugging i saw in stacktrace some refs to ThreadLocalTransactionManager.

And don't know is it useful information, but i don't use spring transaction annotation and instead of that i use exposed `transaction{}` block.

Comment: Do you use Exposed `SpringTransactionManager` to handle Spring transactions?

Comment: @Tapac answered in the post body